# How to properly store and retrieve data using react js context api? The code, I have is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx, react-context

I am learning react. I am trying to store user information after fetching the data from an api endpoint and store it in context. The problem is I have to execute the function in every webpage to access the information stored in it. I tried using `useEffect` in App.js to fetch the data and use it in header and sidebar, but then it works only in that file.

I have routers since I have multiple pages in my website. Are there any problems with the code which restricts the data getting stored in context and how to properly do this with routers.

These are the codes I have,

reducer.js

```
export const initialState = {
user: null,
};

export const actionTypes = {
    SET_USER: 'SET_USER',
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    // console.log(action);
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.SET_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.user,
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};


export default reducer;
```

stateprovider.js

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>

);

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

Below is the function which I need to call in `useEffect` in every page, for user information to get displayed in header and sidebar.

```
const [state, dispatch] = useStateValue()

const userInfo = async function userProfileInfo() {
    axiosInstance.get('accounts/data/view/').then((res) => {
        const currentUser = res.data;
        dispatch({
            type: actionTypes.SET_USER,
            user: currentUser,
        })

        })
}

useEffect(() => {
    userInfo()

}, [])
```

index.js

```
const routing = (
    <Router>
        
            <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
                       
                <div className="body">
                    <Switch>
                        
                        <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
                        .
                        .
                        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
                        <Route exact path="/myprofile" component={PostMyProfile} />
                        .
        </Switch>
       </div>
    </StateProvider>

        
    </Router>
```

header.js

```
const [state, dispatch] = useStateValue();
console.log(state.user)

<div className="header__info">
    <Avatar src= {state.user?.display_pic} alt=""/>
    <h4>{state.user?.username}</h4>
</div>
```

Is it necessary to call this function in every page? There should be a proper way to do this I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `userInfo` function again and again. You have to call it at the beginning and at that time it will save the user information in the state. So you can access state values from any component as you want. Use below code to access your state

```
const [state, dispatch] = useStateValue();

<p>{state.user}</p>
```

I have updated your code and added it into codesandbox. Please check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-ishizaka-nh1u3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the response. So in other pages, for eg, if it isn't App.js and is in another file, the user profile page, then should I repeat the same thing again? or is there a shortcut to access the value?

Comment: You have to use `useStateValue()` function in order to access the state in other pages

Comment: You mean to just call this `const [state, dispatch] = useStateValue();`?

Comment: I tried this, but the problem is, apart from the app.js page, the username is not showing on the sidebar and header for other pages.

Comment: Yes, No need to call `userInfo` function again and again, But you need to call this function one time in order to get the user

Comment: Yeah. I called this function in App.js, but something's wrong as it isn't showing with other pages even though the header component and sidebar are same for every page.

Comment: if you can update the code, then I can have a look at it

Comment: This is the same function, I am currently using in all pages to display username in header . I will update the header part in the question. When I console out in app.js, I am getting the values, in other pages it is null.

Comment: Please check this. https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-sky-686g8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will check that out! :)